# Lua specifying library

Tags: lua, require

Within my Lua scripts, I have multiple libraries using the same 'structure'.
For example, I have a.lua what contains 'require('b')' and require('c').
Both b.lua and c.lua have got an info function. b.lua let it print "b" and c.lua let it print "c". Now I want to be able to specify what one I use in a.lua.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your 'b' and 'c' modules into different namespaces by using tables and then explicitly qualify which one to use from `a.lua`. For example:

```
-- b.lua
local function info()
  print "b"
end

return { info = info }
```

---

```
-- c.lua
-- another style
local M = {}
function M.info()
  print "c"
end

return M
```

---

```
-- a.lua
b = require 'b'
c = require 'c'

b.info()  -- prints "b"
c.info()  -- prints "c"

local info = b.info -- ok you really want 'b'
info()    -- prints "b"
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get errors using coroutines. Do you have a solution for that, too?

Comment: @scheurneus You should ask that as a new question.